# editing autofollow with salesforce chatter

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

So I have this idea to add a field to Contacts, where they autofollow Users they are associated with. My Idea is to be able to have User A create Contact A, and Contact A to be associated with (And hence autofollowing) User A, B, and C.

Does anyone know of a plugin that does this/have any idea of where I should start doing this? I just can't figure out how to edit the Chatter code on an enterprise account, or add functionalities to the Chatter codebase.

Is this possible? Any ideas of where to start would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact method would depend a bit on your contact-users association. You could write a trigger on contact insert/update and make userEntitity records between the user who made the contact record and the associated users.

Have a look at the chatter cheat sheet: http://developerforce.s3.amazonaws.com/website/pdfs/Chatter-cheatsheet_final.pdf

ps: you may get more response at  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ , which is specialized on salesforce subjects.

Comment: The idea of a trigger + the chatter cheatsheet worked to point me in the right direction, thank you!